# Data holding and watching in service to update view in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, watch

I use AngularJS on the client side to display some informations that'll get pushed through a NodeJS-Server. The data will be held in a service factory.

I want to watch this data through the angular watch function.

The problem i run into, is the following. watch runs through the factory only once and stops.

And if the server pushes changed data it won't update the view?

Here  is some code snippet.

```
.factory('clientStorage', ['socket', function (socket){
    var that = {};

    //basis data
    that.basisData = {};
    that.getBasisData = function () {
        socket.on('sendBasis', function (basis) {
            console.log('ich hoffe doch');
            that.basisData = basis;
            console.log(that.basisData);
        });
        console.log(that.basisData);
        return that.basisData;
        };
    return that;
}]);
```

I don't know why this happens?

Anybody there who may help?

Greetings

Henrik

Comment: Can you add your controller to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch( function() { return clientStorage.basisData; }, function(clientData) {
    $scope.data = clientData;
});
```

Where `$scope.data` is the data you are trying to update.